# How do I elegantly repartition my hard drive?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, partition-table

My /home partition (/dev/sda7) is running out of space and now I realize I should have put more space in my /home partition instead of my Windows partition (because I don't use Windows very much anymore). What I want to do is to reduce the Windows partition (simple enough) and then have additional /home space from the space left behind by the shrunk Windows partition (NTFS, /dev/sda1). Is there a way of doing this without losing any data and maintaining a singular /home partition (or if two /home partitions can be seen as one)? An image of my GPT hard drive's filesystem is attached below.

Thanks

[image: GPT hard drive partitions]

Answer (score 1):

Using LVM may be the best choice to avoid difficult and dangerous disk operations. Still, repartitioning can be done, but the process is lengthy and error prone. I can't say which of the partitioning tools available are reliable enough to be trustworthy. So sit back and really think about what you are doing.

- reduce the NTFS file system to an adequate size
- reduce the NTFS partition to the same (or so) space
- move all partitions to just after the previous partition
- resize / increase the target home partition
- resize / increase the home file system.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add the to-be unallocated space residing after your Windows partition to your `/home` partition because you have other partitions between them.

What you can do is create an LVM volume group out of both partitions and then create a logical volume (not the same thing as a logical partition) in the volume group. By placing your `/home` into a logical volume you'd be able to use the space provided by both partitions, minus some overhead in storage space and computation.

LVM, partitioning, etc are well covered in this stackexchange forum, so detailed steps are beyond the scope of any one question.

My recommendation is to research LVM and decide if it's right for you. If so, create a plan for how you're going to migrate your `/home` to LVM, again by researching and asking *specific* questions. Note that taking a working backup of `/home` should be a part of your plan. Then, execute your plan :)